# Set primary domain for Azure web app (Wordpress) to www

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I'm having trouble making my Wordpress custom domain map the way I want. What I would like is for my domain to always rewrite to the "www" version, so www.mydomain.com instead of having both the www.mydomain.com and the mydomain.com both. I know that both have to be mapped to create the vhost in Azure's service (I've seen this non-answer to my question.) I did find a way to do this in a way by removing the below from the Wordpress config and then setting the www domain in the Wordpress database:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/wp-content');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

I've found though, that by doing this when I set up a CDN end point to pull from the webapp origin, it does not pull correctly (on all 3 tiers,) I suppose because it can't access the default azurewebsites.net domain. And if you just use a custom origin, it will not resolve the files. I found this out because my sites that were not mapped with a domain would resolve all of their CDN files, while the custom domains would fail.

So, there has to be a way from the web.config file to just rewrite the non-www to the www, no? I've looked around and haven't found a straight answer. I did find the below here on StackOverflow, but it simply causes a server error for me:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

What am I missing?

I do not want both the www and the non-www to be visible, as I know some search engines will mark them as duplicate content and penalize the listing. It's also not best practice imo to have both. One should just rewrite to the other, whichever your preference.

Comment: You say it causes a server error. Any more specific error message? Does the error occur before you get the redirect or before? Check your browser's F12 tools to see if you get the redirect or not.

Comment: According to your description, I assumed that you have mapped both www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com to your Azure Web App as host names. Also, the rewrite rule you provided is correct. Have you tried to check the steps provided by juunas?